# trying to add listbox inside listboxitem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to use  listbox inside listboxitem in WPF

Here , icTodoList and ActivityListBox are two main Lists. i want to add same number of lists in ActivityListBox as icTodoList and further i want to add one listbox under each listViewItem
The problem that is coming with this code is that it only binds listboxitem not listbox under wrap panel.

please let me know where i am wrong

```
for (var i = 0; i < icTodoList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();
    lb.Name = "InnerActivityList";
    lb.Height = 500;
    lb.Width = 225;
    lb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    lbi.Content = lb;
    ActivityListBox.Items.Add(lbi);
}
```

Comment: `please let me know where i am wrong` - You're using procedural code to *create* a UI in WPF, as opposed to properly *defining* the UI in declarative XAML and using proper **DataBinding** to show data on it. It is strongly recommended that you delete all this code and start reading [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ListBoxItem is a content control.  You are populating only the properties of its ancestor class, the Framework Element!  That's where you are going wrong.  In addition to HighCore's comment.